# Apache 403 after configuring varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish, debugging, http-status-code-403

I just don't know where else to look and what else to do. I keep getting a 403 error on all my vhosts after setting varnish 3.0

Apacher log:

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration:
>   /etc/apache2/htdocs

Headers:

```
http://domain.com/

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=106762181.277908140.1348005089.1354040972.1354058508.6; __utmz=106762181.1348005089.1.1.utmcsr=OTHERDOMAIN.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/galerias/cocinas
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Cacheable: YES
Content-Length: 223
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2012 20:35:14 GMT
X-Varnish: 1030961813 1030961811
Age: 26
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: HIT
----------------------------------------------------------
```

`/etc/default/varnish`:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a ip.ip.ip.ip:80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/main.domain.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
             #-s malloc,256m"
```

My vcl file: http://pastebin.com/axJ57kD8

So, any ideas what I could be missing?

### Update

Just so you know, ports:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
Listen 8000
```

and `<VirtualHost 205.13.12.12:8000>`

Comment: Why is your Apache configuration set to serve documents from `/etc/apache2/htdocs`?

Comment: If the requests are getting the Apache you have something in the access config there Denying the requests from Varnish. Did you change anything in httpd.conf for Varnish? What access rules to you have?

Comment: @mindthemonkey I have the default apache2.conf can't figure it out why only happens with varnish on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sending requests to `127.0.0.1:8000`, which the server is listening on but your virtual host is configured for `205.13.12.12:8000`.

When a virtual host is not matched it will try and serve the default site which, from the error, looks like a `DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/htdocs` which might not have correct permissions, or exist, or be configured in `httpd.conf` correctly for access, whatever it is doesn't really matter unless you plan on using it at some stage.

Point Varnish at the interface IP `205.13.12.12`
or
[Configure your virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) to work with `127.0.0.1`
or
Use the `_default_` special name [in the same docco](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) if this virtual host should be the default.